# PHP explode string into array with space delimiter when string has multiple spaces?

Tags: php

My PHP code below will explode a string into array.  It allows to use multiple delimiters for detecting where the array values should be  from the string.

In the demo one of the delimiter values is a space.  The problem is if the string has more than 1 consecutive space, it will generate empty array values.

For example `key key2 key3  key4` would generate array with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => key
    [1] => key2
    [2] => key3
    [3] => 
    [4] => key4
)
```

and the desired output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => key
    [1] => key2
    [2] => key3
    [4] => key4
)
```

How can I fix this?

---

```
/**
 * Explode a string into array with multiple delimiters instead of the default 1 delimeter that explode() allows!
 * @param  array $delimiters - array(',', ' ', '|') would make a string with spaces, |, or commas turn into array
 * @param string $string  text with the delimeter values in it that will be truned into an array
 * @return array - array of items created from the string where each delimiter  in string made a new array key
 */
function multiexplode ($delimiters, $string) {
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $array = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    $array = array_map('trim', $array);
    return  $array;
}

$tagsString  = 'PHP JavaScript,WebDev Apollo   jhjhjh';
$tagsArray = multiexplode(array(',',' '), $tagsString);
print_r($tagsArray);
```

---

**Output array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => PHP
    [1] => JavaScript
    [2] => WebDev
    [3] => Apollo
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => jhjhjh
)
```

Comment: Just use preg_split(). Once you start using regular expressions you'll never turn back.

Comment: what bout replacing `$array = array_map('trim', $array);` to `$array = array_filter($array, "strlen");` ? saw this one awhile ago in the php docs to remove space, null, false

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve your problem and simplify the code by using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). You can apply a regex including all delimiters in a [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) with a [quantifier](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) and `\s*` to consume whitespaces around the delimiters.

Code:

```
$array = preg_split("/\s*[" . preg_quote(implode("", $delimiters), "/") . "]+\s*/", $str);
                      └┬┘└────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┘└┬┘ 
      Consuming any whitespaces                   │             Consuming any whitespaces 
      around delimiter                            │             around delimiter
                                   ┌──────────────┘
                                   ├ []           → Character class with quantifier
                                   ├ implode()    → Converting array into a string
                                   └ preg_quote() → Escaping special characters
```

Comment: *Excellent RR!* I was headed for the bull-in-a-China-shop approach with `preg_replace()` then `explode()` like this `$foo_array = explode(' ', preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $str));`

Comment: When imploding with an empty string as the glue, the glue parameter can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use :

```
array_filter($tagsArray);
```

Or use :

```
array_diff( $tagsArray, array( '' ));
```

Comment: Nice simple approach!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a working `preg_split()` answer, but maybe more flexible to just use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`:

```
$tagsArray = preg_split('/[ ,]/', $tagsString, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);  // or '/ |,/'
```

Comment: Would this limit to just 1 type of delimiter though?

Comment: No.  The code uses spaces and commas and you can add whatever you want either separated by the OR `|` operator or in a character class `[]`.